# how do you write over one dynamic value

Tags: jquery

i am dynamically writing two sets of values into a box.

the problem is that i need one of the values to sit over the other value

it might be easier if i show you what i mean

both pictures below show a dynamically produced 'percentage progress bar'.
the problem is that the image on the left is cut short because the percent is only 17%

So, the only way around it is for the  17% Poached to site in the middle of the bar.

below is the code that i use to place the figures

[image]

```
<div class="container"><div class="progressbar"></div></div>

function setProgressOne(progress, product)
{             
    var progressBarWidth = progress*$(".container").width()/ 100;  
    $(".progressbar").width(progressBarWidth).html(progress + "% " + product);
}
```

i tried to change the code to allow me to place the percentage figure seperate from teh blue clouring, but all it did was to eliminating the colouring.

```
function setProgressOne(progress, product)
{             
    var progressBarWidth = progress*$(".container").width()/ 100;  
    $(".progressbar").width(progressBarWidth);

    $(".progressbar").html(progress + "% " + product);
}
```

this is what happened when i ajusted the code above.

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with jquery and everything to do with CSS. Just add a `text-align:center` to your `.progressbar` and make sure the text's parent container is the entire progress bar and not just the current fill of it.

Comment: Hi slime, i have already text aligned it to center. but how would i make sure the text parent container is the entire progress bar? i tried changing the function but it made no diffrence: function setProgressOne(progress, product)
{             
    var progressBarWidth = progress*$(".container").width()/ 100;  
    $(".progressbar").html(progress + "% " + product);
    
    $(".progressbar").width(progressBarWidth);
    
}

Comment: In your image, the text's parent container needs to be the gray outline, not the blue color. And without seeing the HTML, it's hard to give you an exact suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to have 2 `div` elements which contain the label. One which appears 'underneath' the progress bar and another 'above' it. The styling of each would allow for the text to be styled differently to make it easier to read. You could then use CSS to `clip` the upper div to fit the width of the progress bar. Something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="message message-under"></div>
    <div class="progressbar"></div>
    <div class="message message-over"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
}
.message {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.message-under {
    color: #333;
    z-index: 5;
}
.progressbar {
    background-color: #C00;
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}
.message-over {
    color: #FFF;
    z-index: 15;
}
```

```js
function setProgressOne(progress, product) {
    var progressBarWidth = progress * $(".container").width() / 100;
    $(".progressbar").width(progressBarWidth);
    $('.message-over').css('clip', 'rect(0px, ' + progressBarWidth + 'px, 30px, 0px)');
    $('.message').html(progress + "% " + product);
}
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/0LuLhqmb/)

---

*Update*

Here's another demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0LuLhqmb/1/

Note that I made the progress bar draggable so you can see the transition effect from one text style to the other more clearly.

Comment: Hello Rory. thank you so much for your help. it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can set font-size programmatically by calculating against progress bar width.

ex.

```
 $(".progressbar").css({"font-size":progressBarWidth /100 /<someAmount>})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's going to be easier if you put the label in a separate tag, see the code:

```
<div id="bar1" class="barBox">
    <div class="barItself"></div>
    <div class="barLabel"></div>
</div>

function setBarValue(containerId, value, msg){
    var $box = $('#'+containerId);
    var $bar = $box.children('.barItself');
    var $label = $box.children('.barLabel');
    var percent = Math.round(100 * value) + '%';
    $bar.width(percent);
    $label.html(percent + ' ' + msg);
}

setBarValue('bar1', 0.3, 'poached');
```

And a bit more interactive example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5c2zt6ub/3/)